# UDF to filter a map by key in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a Spark DataFrame with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- mapkey: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: array (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- bt: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- bp: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- z: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- w: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- h: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
```

I'd like to write a UDF to filter the mapkey such that the key is equal to uid, and only return the values that pass the filter. I am trying the following:

```
val filterMap = udf((m: Map[String, Seq[Row]], uid: String) => {
    val s = Set(uid)
    m.filterKeys { s.contains(_) == true }
})
```

but I get the following error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Row is not supported
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:762)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:704)
>     at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:809)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:39)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:703)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:722)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:704)
>     at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:809)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:39)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:703)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:726)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:704)
>     at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:809)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:39)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:703)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:700)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.udf(functions.scala:3200)

Can someone point out what's wrong with the UDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your only option is using a case class that matches the internal structure of this `Row`:

```
case class MyStruct(w: Int, h: Int)
case class Element(id: String, bt: String, bp: Double, z: MyStruct)
```

You can then use it in your UDF (surprisingly enough):

```
// sample data:
val df = Seq(
  (Map(
    "key1" -> Array(Element("1", "bt1", 0.1, MyStruct(1, 2)), Element("11", "bt11", 0.2, MyStruct(1, 3))),
    "key2" -> Array(Element("2", "bt2", 0.2, MyStruct(12, 22)))
  ), "key2")
).toDF("mapkey", "uid")

df.printSchema() // prints the right schema, as expected in post

// define UDF:
val filterMap = udf((m: Map[String, Seq[Element]], uid: String) => {
  m.filterKeys(_ == uid)
})

// use UDF:
df.withColumn("result", filterMap($"mapkey", $"uid")).show(false)

// prints:
// +-----------------------------------------------------------------+
// |result                                                           |
// +-----------------------------------------------------------------+
// |Map(key1 -> WrappedArray([1,bt1,0.1,[1,2]], [11,bt11,0.2,[1,3]]))|
// +-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I have not been able to get this method to work. I always get a "spark GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to XXX" error. The only way I found to pass a complex type to a UDF is by passing it as a Row.

Comment: Interesting - perhaps something has changed in the way Spark handles it - this works for me with Spark 2.3.0, I wonder which version you're using. And would be interesting to know if the example above works for you using your version.